# Updating Enumeration

Tags: java, upgrade, enumeration

We've recently moved on from old Java code (from WSED 5.1.2 to RAD 7.5), and I've found that an old Enumeration reference no longer works for us.  Does my new code create the same effect as the old code?

**New Code**

```
Enumeration numer;
Vector numVec = new Vector();
numVec.add(runtimeOptions.keys());
numer = numVec.elements();
while (numer.hasMoreElements())
{
      String key = (String)numer.nextElement();
      System.out.println("   "+key + "=" + (String)runtimeOptions.get(key));
}
```

**Old Code**

```
Enumeration enum = runtimeOptions.keys();
while(enum.hasMoreElements()) 
{
  String key = (String)enum.nextElement();
  System.out.println("   "+key + "=" + (String)runtimeOptions.get(key));
}
```

Comment: `enum` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: My developer was indicating that Enumeration was itself an undefined type, but having now changed the name of my Enumeration, I can see that it works just fine.  Thank you.